# How do I call a function in a threadsafe manner

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have been playing around with methods of calling of calling a method safely in threadsafe manner in .net 2.0.

My treeview is populated from a call to a database on a separate thread;

Below is my attempt to use my InvokeFunction method ( shown below) ...it works, but I was hoping that there was a nicer way to write this...any thoughts on this?

```
InvokeFunction(delegate() { TreeView1.Nodes.Clear(); });



delegate void FunctionDelegate();
private delegate void ThreadSafeProcess(FunctionDelegate func);
private void InvokeFunction(FunctionDelegate func)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    ThreadSafeProcess d = new ThreadSafeProcess(InvokeFunction);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { func });
  }
  else
  {
    func();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this unless you say more about what your function does. There are many many different synchronisation mechanisms available that solve different problems. Which one is appropriate depends on the problem at hand. What is your problem?

Comment: David, as you can see the function is calling a treeview method clear nodes(). I was just playing around with the idea of creating something a little more generic than explicitly calling the forms.control method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is a cleaner solution in .NET 2.0.
It will create a thread for you and take care of synchronization.

You add `BackgroundWorker` component to you Form in the design mode.
You subscribe to `DoWork` event. The method subscribed to this will be execute in a background thread when you call `backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` in your UI thread.

When you need to interact with UI thread from your background thread you call `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress`.
This will trigger `ProgressChanged` event. `ProgressChanged` event is always executed in UI thread.
You can use `userState` parameter of `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress` to pass any data to UI thread. For example in your case the data that is needed to add new `TreeView` nodes.
You will actually add new nodes inside of `ProgressChanged` event handler.

Here is the link to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx.

Keep in mind you don't have to use `percentProgress` parameter of the method `ReportProgress` method. Although it is convenient when you have a progress bar to reflect background work progress.

Comment: I assume that this is WinForms.
Brad said: "My treeview is populated from a call to a database on a separate thread".
TreeView should not be access from any other thread than UI thread. So UI thread synchronization is required here.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry abbout thread safety unless you share some state. Functions always receive their parameters on the stack and stack is local for each thread. So functions are not your problem. Instead focus on the state. "TreeView1" objects is a candidate to worry about.