# How to ensure the GUI elements and loaded before proceeding in C#

Tags: c#

I am a beginner to C#. I am trying to make a simple program that displays the links from a website into a ListBox. Since retrieving the links takes time, my GUI waits till all the links are parsed and ListBox populated before it becomes visible.

I would assume that this is because the InitializeComponent() and my ParseLinks() methods run in the same thread. I would like to know if there is way I could run ParseLinks() after the UI elements are loaded.

```
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ParseLinks();
    }
```

I would appreciate any input. Thanks

[Edit]

More info on `ParseLinks()`: (I am giving the summary since the code is quite extensive)

`ParseLinks()` gets the links into an arraylist and assigns the arraylist to the `ListBox`. The whole operation works very well. But I wanted the GUI to be displayed and then the `ListBox` populated. I am also disabling a Button while at it and also changing a `ProgressBar` Style to `Marquee`. Referring to the response I gave below, when I used `Backgroundworker`, I got multiple cross-thread operation error which I solved by placing the GUI editing code inside one `InvokeRequired` statement

Comment: we can help you with threading and stuff but you need to give the source of ParseLinks, since there will need to be modifications there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, I suggest using BackgroundWorker. Your form would populate ListBox in a background thread.
More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849120/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-a-threadsafe-manner/5849710#5849710).

**[Edit]**

Here is the basic idea:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var newElement = BuildMyElement(i);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, newElement);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newElement = (MyType)e.UserState;
    listBox1.Items.Add(newElement);
}
```

Replace backgroundWorker1_DoWork with the code that you use to retrieve URLs.

Comment: I tried making BackgroundWorker (a bit complicated for a beginner like me) but as I added more elements, I started getting cross-threaded operation errors. I ended up using InvokeRequired to solve those errors. Thanks for the links too.

Comment: @Monk - If you are getting tread exceptions than you use it incorrectly. Whenever you have element to add to the list you should call `ReportProgress(0, yourElement)` and add this element to the list in 'ProgressChanged' event.

Comment: If I were to add more components and also update them alongside the listbox, should I use different background workers. Also, since I am doing the parsing and updating the listbox inside a function, could I call the function using the background worker ? Thanks for the example. It made it quite easy to understand.

Comment: Nevermind. I followed the example. Worked like a charm. Kudos to you my man.

Answer (score 1):

Put in the on form load function.

Comment: did you mean something like this:         protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs eArgs){ParseLinks(); } --- I tried this and still the same result